# App Crashes When NodeJS is Asked to Talk to PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a modicum experience with web development, but the sites I've built to date have all had embedded databases. This is my first attempt at building a website with a *non-embedded* database.

I've built a skeleton site using **NodeJS** and the **Express** framework. It's hosted by **Heroku**. Before I tried to add in the database, the app seemed to work well, as expected.

However, now that I've added a `scraper.js` file to the app, all I get is a notification that the app has crashed. The contents of this file are:

```js
const Finaliser = require("./finaliser.js");
const { Client } = require("pg");
const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: true,
});

class Scraper
{
  constructor()
  {
    this.finaliser = new Finaliser();
  }

  fetchAsIs(req, res)
  {
    var data, columns, rows;
    var tableName = req.params.id;
    var that = this;
    var queryString = "SELECT * FROM "+tableName+";";

    client.connect();
    client.query(queryString, (err, extract) => {
      if(err) throw err;

      client.end();

      console.log(extract);
      that.finaliser.protoRender(req, res, "asis",
                                 { title: tableName });
    });
  }
};

module.exports = Scraper;
```

**Extra details:**

- Running `heroku logs --tail` gives:

```
2019-10-23T15:35:50.281517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=harvesthub.herokuapp.com request_id=caadba91-9b2d-4525-9c9c-19c34733073d fwd="194.33.13.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-23T15:35:50.588155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=harvesthub.herokuapp.com request_id=28b7948f-ff59-44f0-867a-f3ce7ede86cc fwd="194.33.13.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

- I think the database is set up correctly. Running `heroku addons --app harvesthub` gives:

```
Add-on                                            Plan       Price  State  
────────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────  ─────  ───────
heroku-postgresql (postgresql-crystalline-06305)  hobby-dev  free   created
 └─ as DATABASE

The table above shows add-ons and the attachments to the current app (harvesthub) or other apps.
```

- The repository for the app's source code is https://github.com/tomhosker/harvesthub.
- I know that `"SELECT * FROM "+tableName+";"` is a recipe for sorrow. I'll change it later.
- Sorry for such a long question!

Comment: when you say app crashed, what do you mean? what was the error?

Comment: In the browser, I get a message from Heroku which reads: "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served..." The same message goes on to point the app owner to `heroku logs --tail`. See the details section of my original question to see what running this command returns.

Comment: I believe you are missing dependencies `pg` and `dotenv`.  Install them by running `npm install --save pg dotenv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had failed to install the `pg` and `dotenv` packages properly. (I had *attempted* to install them, but for some reason it didn't take.)

To anyone finding himself in the same position as me: double check that `pg` and `dotenv` are in your `package.json` file. If they're missing, run `npm install --save pg dotenv` to install them.

Heartfelt thanks to Justin Moser. This answer is just a fleshing out of his comment.